# Warning while using geometry Tufte book style - (Over-specification in `v'-direction)

Tags: geometry, warnings, tufte, marginpar, height

I try to adjust the page layout of my `tufte-book` document using the `geometry` package. A warning appears while I change the vertical layout, maybe its due to a missing field in my geometry declaration? Can somebody clarify the rules to set the `width/height` without having any warning? Here is the warning

```
Package geometry Warning: Over-specification in `v'-direction. `height' (686.0pt) is ignored.
```

Note that margin vertical delimiters don't appear while using the `showframe` debug option for the `geometry` package. I already try the `marginfix` but it don't solve the issue neither.

I'm working with the `pdfLaTex` compiler and here is my minimal code

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\geometry{
    showframe,
    left=15mm,
    textwidth=140mm,
    headsep=4mm,
    headheight = 14pt,
    marginparsep=5mm,
    marginparwidth=50.6mm,
    bottom = 2cm, 
    top = 1.7cm
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\marginnote{\lipsum[2]}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The tufte classes also use geometry to specify the layout, and these parameters are used if you did not override them. And that includes both the `textheight` and `paperheight` parameters. Now all the vertical sizes that you gave, and `textheight` should add up to `paperheight`, but it doesn't. So `geomerty has to decide whether to throw away` textheight`or`paperheight`. It has chosen to throw away` textheight`(in the form of the`height` parameter, which in your case is the same).

As you specify almost the complete layout, I would suggest to ignore tha standard tufte parameters by adding `reset` to your `geometry` call. Maybe you should also add a papersize specification.

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\geometry{
    reset, % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    showframe,
    left=15mm,
    textwidth=140mm,
    headsep=4mm,
    headheight = 14pt,
    marginparsep=5mm,
    marginparwidth=50.6mm,
    bottom = 2cm, 
    top = 1.7cm
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\marginnote{\lipsum[2]}

\end{document}
```